# AWS Rekognition - index faces

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, face-recognition, amazon-rekognition

when I upload an image for example with 6 pepoles to collection and index the faces is there a way to know if 2 pepole exist alredy and to index only the 4 others?

also the search face by image is return only an array of the same person even if there are more pepoles on the image that I index them what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

There is nothing on documention on AWS that i can finde to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

When calling `IndexFaces()`, Amazon Rekognition will add up to 100 Faces to a Face Collection.

If the same image is being used was previously indexed with `IndexFaces()`, then a duplicate will not be stored. However, if the same person was previously indexed with a different image, then they *will* be added as a duplicate. This is because Amazon Rekognition does not 100% know that this person is a duplicate, since the source image was different.

As per the documentation, if you want to avoid Faces that *seem* to be duplicates, you could first call `DetectFaces()` to find the faces in the image and then use the bounding boxes in the response to make face crops, which then you can pass in to the `SearchFacesByImage()` operation. If the match is below your desired threshold, then you could add the Face to the Face Collection. If the match is *above* your desired threshold, then you could assume that the Face is already in the Face Collection.

`SearchFacesByImage()` will only return information about the *largest* face in the image. It returns an array of Faces that possibly match that largest face.

From [SearchFacesByImage - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_SearchFacesByImage.html):

> For a given input image, first detects the largest face in the image, and then searches the specified collection for matching faces.
> ...
> **Note**
> To search for all faces in an input image, you might first call the `IndexFaces` operation, and then use the face IDs returned in subsequent calls to the `SearchFaces` operation.
>
> You can also call the `DetectFaces` operation and use the bounding boxes in the response to make face crops, which then you can pass in to the `SearchFacesByImage` operation.